# Creating "zero state" migration for existing db with sqlalchemy/alembic and "faking" zero migration for that existing db

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I want to add alembic to an existing ,sqlalchemy using, project, with a working production db. I fail to find what's the standard way to do a "zero" migration == the migration setting up the db as it is now (For new developers setting up their environment)

Currently I've added import the declarative base class and all the models using it to the env.py , but first time `alembic -c alembic.dev.ini revision  --autogenerate` does create the existing tables.

And I need to "fake" the migration on existing installations - using code. For django ORM I know how to make this work, but I fail to find what's the right way to do this with sqlalchemy/alembic

Answer (score 52):

`alembic revision --autogenerate` inspects the state of the connected database and the state of the target `metadata` and then creates a migration that brings the `database` in line with `metadata`.

If you are introducing `alembic/sqlalchemy` to an existing database, and you want a migration file that given an empty, fresh database would reproduce the current state- follow these steps.

1. Ensure that your `metadata` is truly in line with your current `database`(i.e. ensure that running `alembic revision --autogenerate` creates a migration with zero operations).
2. Create a new `temp_db` that is empty and point your `sqlalchemy.url` in `alembic.ini` to this new `temp_db.`
3. Run `alembic revision --autogenerate`. This will create your desired bulk migration that brings a fresh db in line with the current one.
4. Remove `temp_db` and re-point `sqlalchemy.url` to your existing database.
5. Run `alembic stamp head`. This tells sqlalchemy that the current migration represents the state of the database- so next time you run `alembic upgrade head` it will begin from this migration.

Comment: This wasn't so obvious to me, so this may be useful to others too : be sure to delete the empty revision file generated in alembic's versions directory during step 1) before running step 3) Otherwise, you will get a "Database is not up to date" error.

Comment: I think this needs a step 1.5: remove the migration file (with zero operations) which was created. No?

Answer (score 14):

## New installation: applying the migration

Simply run `alembic upgrade head` against an empty database.  This will apply all the migrations (in your case, the initial migration as it's the only one) to the database.

If you want to do this from code rather than from shell, you can do it the following way:

```
from alembic.config import Config
from alembic import command
alembic_cfg = Config("/path/to/yourapp/alembic.ini")
command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, "head")
```

## Existing installation: faking the migration

### SQL way

One way would be running this SQL against the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alembic_version (
    version_num VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO alembic_version (version_num) VALUES ('your initial migration version');
```

The first statement creates the table that alembic uses to track your database/migration state.  The second statement basically tells alembic that your database state corresponds to the version of your initial migration, or, in other words, fakes the migration.

### Alembic way

Alembic has a `stamp` command, which basically does the same thing.  It can be called from shell as `alembic stamp head`, or from code (taken from the [cookbook](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html#building-an-up-to-date-database-from-scratch)):

```
from alembic.config import Config
from alembic import command
alembic_cfg = Config("/path/to/yourapp/alembic.ini")
command.stamp(alembic_cfg, "head")
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, the problems with this answer:
1. It does not answer the "how to create zero state db for new devs"
2. It's direct SQL vs the db, while this might be the simplest, I would prefer a code driven solution for this problem

Comment: @alonisser I've expanded the answer, hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed a slightly different path then michael_j_ward which did not require the creation of an empty database. For the project I'm working on, there are different schemas in the db and for this app, the data is in a separate schema. In alembic you can specify which schema alembic should perform operations on by defining an include_name function in the `env.py` file:

```py
def include_name(name, type_, parent_names):
    if type_ == "schema":
        return name == "your_schema"
    else:
        return True
```

By setting the schema to a nonexistent value, it generates all tables and columns from scratch (since there is nothing there yet) in the migration.

After that, switch back to your original schema in the include_name function.

The configure arguments in the run_migrations_online method look like this when working with specific schema's

```
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            include_schemas=True,
            include_name=include_name,
            target_metadata=get_metadata(),
            version_table_schema="your_schema", # alembic_version table is created in this schema
            **conf_args
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

## Generate Models for an Existing DB

You can use [sqlacodegen](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen) to create your models from introspection of an existing database.

If you already have sqlalchemy models, compare the generated models to your models and adjust them accordingly.

Then you can run `alembic revision --autogenerate` to create the initial migration.

To ensure that your sqlalchemy models will create the same schema as the original DB you can use tools like [liquibase](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase), [flyway](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/) or [bytebase](https://github.com/bytebase/bytebase) to compare the diff of your original schema to the sqlachemy/alembic generated schema.