# How to initialize Alembic on an existing DB

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have an existing app which uses SQLAlchemy for DB access. It works well.

Now I want to introduce DB migrations, and I read alembic is the recommended way. Basically I want to start with the "current DB state" (not empty DB!) as revision 0, and then track further revisions going forward.

So I installed alembic (version 1.7.3) and put

```py
from my_project.db_tables import Base
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

into my `env.py`. The `Base` is just standard SQLAlchemy `Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()` within my project (again, which works fine).

Then I ran `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "revision0"`, expecting to see an `upgrade()` method that gets me to the current DB state from an empty DB. Or maybe an empty `upgrade()`, since it's the first revision, I don't know.

Instead, the `upgrade()` method is full of `op.drop_index` and `op.drop_table` calls, while `downgrade()` is all `op.create_index` and `op.create_table`. Basically the opposite of what I expected.

Any idea what's wrong?
What's the recommended way to "initialize" migrations from an existing DB state?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132288/2144390

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52121596/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks. The first link is not relevant (I don't use upper case). The second link might be – clearly even the first step there fails: `alembic revision --autogenerate` creates a monstrous file, as described in the OP. Still not sure what to do though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.

The existing production DB has lots of stuff that `alembic revision --autogenerate` is not picking up on. That's why its generated migration scripts are full of `op.drop`s in `upgrade()`, and `op.create`s in `downgrade()`.

So I'll have to manually clean up the generated scripts every time. Or automate this cleanup Python script cleanup somehow programmatically, outside of Alembic.